# Column not found because I have different column names in my table

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have some issue when I want to count the rows from relation table.

I have 2 tables `users` and `threads`; I want to count all threads by `id_user`.

This in `User` model

```
public function thread() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Thread');
}
    
protected $primaryKey = "id";
```

This is the `Thread` model

```
protected $primaryKey = "id";

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id_users');
}
```

I try to count in my view like this

```
{{$users->thread->count()}}
```

and this is my index method in controller

```
public function index()
{
    $users = Auth::user();
    $threads = Thread::orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->get();

    return view('/home',compact('threads','users'));
}
```

I just put descending for showing data in my controller.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Do you get an error? Use `{{ dd($users) }}` in your blade to debug the users model. (I suggest renaming your relations/variables to make relations clearer: `public function threads(){...` and `$user = Auth::user();`) You most likely need `->with('thread')` on your `$users` to load the relations. More on counting relations in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: i use dd, no error just displaying raw data from model user, i try adding ->with('thread') like your suggestion that was error appears
and i try change code in my view with {{$threads->count()}} thats work, but count all data, not count data short by user id like i want

Comment: case close
ive done with my issue
solved